# Why `celery.current_app` refers the default instance inside Flask view functions

Tags: python, flask, thread-safety, celery

I'm not trying to use `celery.current_app` inside the view function, but I have a function hooked to the `after_task_publish` signal which is using it to update the state after the task is published, it's working outside the Flask view function and updating the state correctly, but when I send the task from inside the view function the task state won't be updated, I checked and the problem is that the `current_app.backend` is an instance of `DisabledBackend` which is the default instead of being an instance of `RedisBackend` which I'm using.

This is happening because inside the Flask view function the proxy to the current Celery instance `celery.current_app` is referring to the default instance which is created when there's no current Celery instance.

I tried reproducing what's happening and here's a test script:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, print_function, unicode_literals

from flask import Flask, request

from celery import Celery, current_app
from celery.signals import after_task_publish
# internal module for debugging purposes
from celery._state import default_app, _tls


# the flask application
flask_app = Flask(__name__)

# the celery application
celery_app = Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://', backend='redis://')

# debugging info
debug = """
[{location}]
celery_app       = {celery_app}
current_app      = {current_app}
add.app          = {add_app}
default_app      = {default_app}
_tls.current_app = {tls_current_app}
"""

print(debug.format(
    location = 'OUTSIDE VIEW',
    celery_app = celery_app,
    current_app = current_app,
    add_app = add.app,
    default_app = default_app,
    tls_current_app = _tls.current_app
))


# fired after a task is published
@after_task_publish.connect
def after_publish(sender=None, body=None, **kwargs):
    print(debug.format(
        location = 'INSIDE SIGNAL FUNCTION',
        celery_app = celery_app,
        current_app = current_app,
        add_app = add.app,
        default_app = default_app,
        tls_current_app = _tls.current_app
    ))

# a simple task for testing
@celery_app.task(name='add')
def add(a, b):
    return a + b


@flask_app.route('/add')
def add_view():
    print(debug.format(
        location = 'INSIDE VIEW',
        celery_app = celery_app,
        current_app = current_app,
        add_app = add.app,
        default_app = default_app,
        tls_current_app = _tls.current_app
    ))

    a = request.args.get('a')
    b = request.args.get('b')

    task = add.delay(a, b)

    return task.task_id


if __name__ == '__main__':
    flask_app.run(debug=True)
```

And here's the output:

```
[OUTSIDE VIEW]
celery_app       = <Celery tasks:0xb69ede4c>
current_app      = <Celery tasks:0xb69ede4c>
add.app          = <Celery tasks:0xb69ede4c>
default_app      = None
_tls.current_app = <Celery tasks:0xb69ede4c>


[INSIDE VIEW]
celery_app       = <Celery tasks:0xb69ede4c>
current_app      = <Celery default:0xb6b0546c>
add.app          = <Celery tasks:0xb69ede4c>
default_app      = None
_tls.current_app = None   # making current_app fallback to the default instance


[INSIDE SIGNAL FUNCTION]
celery_app       = <Celery tasks:0xb69ede4c>
current_app      = <Celery default:0xb6a174ec>
add.app          = <Celery tasks:0xb69ede4c>
default_app      = None
_tls.current_app = None
```

Because `_tls.current_app` is None inside the view, this is why the `celery.current_app` is refering to the default instance, from `celery._state._get_current_app`:

```
return _tls.current_app or default_app
```

`_tls` is an instance of `celery._state._TLS`:

```
class _TLS(threading.local):
    #: Apps with the :attr:`~celery.app.base.BaseApp.set_as_current` attribute
    #: sets this, so it will always contain the last instantiated app,
    #: and is the default app returned by :func:`app_or_default`.
    current_app = None
```

Is the problem related to threading ? could this be a bug ? or is this an expected behavior ?

Note that I can use the actual celery instance in my hooked function and everything will work just fine, but I'm concerned about `celery.current_app` that is used somewhere else that will break  my code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found the problem when I ran the Flask app without debugging enabled and it worked without any problems, when `debug` is `True` the reloader is used which runs the app in another thread, this happens in `werkzeug._reloader.run_with_reloader` function.

And depending on the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.local) about the class `threading.local` which is subclassed to store the current app instance:

> A class that represents thread-local data. Thread-local data are data whose **values are thread specific**.
>
> The instance’s values will be different for separate threads.

So this means that `celery._state._tls.current_app` is not shared between threads, and we have to set the celery instance manually as the current app, for example in the view function:

```
celery_app.set_current()
```

Comment: FYI, you can determine if you're currently running under the Werkzeug reloader with `os.environ.get('WERKZEUG_RUN_MAIN') == 'true'`

Comment: Not exactly sure if we have the same scenario, but I used celery's `set_default`, as it works across all threads ...
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.html#celery.Celery.set_default

Comment: Thanks @DanielDubovski. Just what I need: `celery_app.set_default()` which is much simpler workaround than modifying each of our tasks to have fully bootstrapped app (e.g. `DownloadFileTask.AsyncResult(task_id)`. Apparently, `set_default()` auto-binds the fully bootstrapped app to all `AsyncResult()` calls.